# Change color of element in table [ng-class] based on a condition

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-class

I'm stuck and I need some help.

I have a table with column name `deadLine`.

The data came from MySQL and is `DATETIME` properties. I've created a function that checks if the date in the column has passed today's date.
Now I want that if the condition is `true`, that specific element in the table should be the color red.

This is my component:

```html
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReportsService } from '../../../../core/services/reports.service';
import { Reports } from 'src/app/shared/entity/reports.entity';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';
import { Utils } from '../../../../shared/utils';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-reports',
    templateUrl: './reports.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reports.component.sass'],
    providers: [
        { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useValue: Utils.hebrewPaginator() }
    ]
})
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {
    public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Reports>;
    public displayedColumns: string[] = ['deadLine', 'year', 'type', 'companyID', 'companyName'];
    @ViewChild('paginator', { read: MatPaginator, static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    filterBool: Boolean;
    dataForFilter: Array<Reports>;


    constructor(private service: ReportsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getReports((data) => this.onGetReportsList(data));

    }
    onGetReportsList(data) {
        data.map((report) => {
            const format = 'yyyy.MM.dd';
            const locale = 'en-US';
            report.deadLine = formatDate(report.deadLine, format, locale);
            const repDate = new Date(report.deadLine).getTime();
            const nowDay = new Date().getTime();
            if (nowDay > repDate) {
                report.deadLine += '*';
            }
        });
        this.dataForFilter = data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Reports>(data);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML file.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-menu">
        <app-home-menu (filterEvent)="applyFilter($event)" [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-home-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="companyName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CompanyNme </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.companyName}} </td>
            </ng-container>


            <ng-container matColumnDef="companyID">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> HP </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.companyID}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>


            <ng-container matColumnDef="year">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Year </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.year}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="deadLine">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DeadLine </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deadLine}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the entire row to be red or a particular cell?

Comment: No i want just the date element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just add the color `red`, the easiest way would be to dynamically add the style based on whether the `deadLine` has an asterisk `*` since you are adding it for the deadlines that have passed.

```html
<td mat-cell [style.color]="isDue(element.deadLine) ? 'red' : ''" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deadLine}} </td>
```

If you want to add a class, use `ngClass`

```html
<td mat-cell [ngClass]="{'deadline': isDue(element.deadLine)}" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deadLine}} </td>
<!-- OR -->
<td mat-cell [class.deadline]="isDue(element.deadLine)" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deadLine}} </td>
```

where the `isDue` function looks like this

```js
today: number = new Date().getTime();

isDue(date): boolean {
    return this.today > new Date(date).getTime();
}
```

and the `deadline` class is

```css
.deadline {
    color: red;
    /* Add other css properties here */
}
```

Comment: In the original case i not add a  * , i need to color the element in red without a *. I had it to check if the condition work. How i color it without the * ??

Comment: Just add `!` to the condition, I have updated my answer to show the same

Comment: I mean that i need way that in the condition i make somthing else and not add * , i add the * for test

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire row to be highlighted you can

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [class.highlightRow]="highlight(row)"></tr>
```

In case you just want to highlight the cell

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="deadLine">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DeadLine </th>
                <td mat-cell [class.highlightRow]="highlight(element)" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deadLine}} 
                </td>
</ng-container>
```

In .ts file

```
highlight(row) {
  //Check if condition true or false
  if(true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

As per the code if the condition is true the class 'highlightRow' will be applied to that particular row and you can style it accordingly in css.

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgypvo

Comment: I want just the deadLine element (date) be red

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirement. Happy Coding :)

Comment: From my point of view this is the better answer because it shows how to add a class to a complete mat-row instead of just mat-cells.